# Display number of accounts on network profile page

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, network-profile

The user profile pages ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/230261/jason-c)) display the number of accounts next to the account list:

[image]

The network profile page ([example](https://stackexchange.com/users/305991/jason-c?tab=accounts)) does not display this info:

[image]

I think it would be handy if the number of accounts were displayed on the network profile page, and also consistent with the accounts list on the user profile page (I'd expect the network profile page to provide *more* info, not less, in any case).